# How to get Chase Paymentech hostedSecureID and hostedSecureAPIToken to make the uID init Request

Tags: payment-gateway

As per the document we have to make a Server to Server call to get the uID
Can some please share the steps/screenshots from where I can get hostedSecureID and hostedSecureAPIToken

I couldn't find these .

https://www.chasepaymentechhostedpay- var.com/direct/services/request/init/?hostedSecureID=xxxx&hostedSecureAPIToken=xxxx&action=buildF orm&css_url=xxxx&callback_url=xxxx&sessionId=xxxx&amount=1.00&orderId=hps123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-chase-paymentech-payment-gateway/

Need to contact Chase Support to get

Secure Account ID – This information about your Chase account is provided only by Chase, and if you do not have this information, you’ll need to contact your Chase Representative to obtain it.

Secure API Token – This information about your Chase account is provided only by Chase, and if you do not have this information, you’ll need to contact your Chase Representative to obtain it.